# What does the passed parameter 'guard' check in underscore.js functions?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

> Get the first element of an array. Passing n will return the first N
>   values in the array. Aliased as head and take. The guard check allows
>   it to work with _.map.

```
  _.first = _.head = _.take = function(array, n, guard) {
    if (array == null) return void 0;
    return (n != null) && !guard ? slice.call(array, 0, n) : array[0];
  };
```

What is the use of the variable 'guard' in this underscore.js function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the source code:

```
  // Get the first element of an array. Passing **n** will return the first N
  // values in the array. Aliased as `head` and `take`. The **guard** check
  // allows it to work with `_.map`.
  _.first = _.head = _.take = function(array, n, guard) {
    if (array == null) return void 0;
    return (n != null) && !guard ? slice.call(array, 0, n) : array[0];
  };
```

> The **guard** check allows it to work with `_.map`.

So if you have an array like this:

```
var a = [ [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6] ];
// put this array though _.map and _.first
_.map(a, _.first); // [1, 4]
```

If this wasn't the case you result would look like this:

```
[ [], [4] ]
```

Because of the arguments going into `_.map`:

```
_.map(['a', 'b', 'c'], function(val, key, obj) {
    // key = 0, 1, 2
    // val = a, b, c
    // obj = ['a', 'b', 'c'] 
    // the obj argument is why `guard` is truly and the first element in the array is returned rater than using [].slice
});
```

---

Its not beautiful but it allows it to work together:

```
_.first([1, 2, 3], 2) // [1, 2]
_.first([1, 2, 3], 2, true) // 1
_.first([1, 2, 3], 2, 3) // 1
```

Comment: According to [the Standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.19), `Array#map` passes *three* arguments to the callback, not two: "*`callbackfn` is called with three arguments: the value of the element, the index of the element, and the object being traversed.*"

Comment: @DCoder This is correct and that is actually why the `_.first` function is returning the first value :) Thanks